# How can I make a controller work on my Android tablet using a USB-OTG cable?

Tags: 4.2-jelly-bean, usb-on-the-go, usb-peripherals, onda-tablet

I am trying to make my Thurstmaster GP XID controller (https://www.thrustmaster.com/products/gp-xid-pc) work on my android 4.2 device (Onda v975s) by plugging it into the micro USB port using a USB-OTG cable.

Many articles say you just need to plug it and play, but my controller is unresponsive. The light of the center button (the home? button) does not light up. I have tried USB diagnostics and controller "tester" apps which do not detect my controller.

My tablet can use a peripheral keyboard plugged by OTG, but a regular USB mouse will not work (won't light up, response etc).

Do not hesitate to ask for more information, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most likely explanation is that your tablet is missing the drivers needed to use USB mice and game controllers. If that's the case, then the only way to make the device work is to find another ROM for your tablet that does have the drivers. You might ask the manufacturer for an updated ROM that has the support, or look for a third-party ROM that supports your tablet (which is unlikely for unpopular devices). Installing a third-party ROM is not easy, though, and if you do it wrong you may break the tablet completely.

It's a bit odd that the manufacturer would choose to remove support for USB mice and game controllers, given that the support is in stock Android. Possibly they had to cut corners to make the kernel fit into the boot image, or something like that.

Comment: Is there a way to install those drivers without another ROM? It has been a nightmare for me to update (or rather unsuccessfully update) this device due to the manufacturer's ineptitude. I could try installing the official 4.4 ROM but that would render my device without WiFi connection (I have an unsolved question regarding this matter, and the only solution I found was to downgrade to 4.2...)

Comment: @Golokopitenko Not unless you have the kernel configuration that was used to make the ROM in the first place.

Comment: Is it possible... That I install win10 on my tablet? That would surely fix all the ROM problems I have with both 4.2 and 4.4

Comment: @Golokopitenko Unless Microsoft have ported Windows to your tablet, it's not possible. I'm afraid the only fix is to steer clear of devices with poorly integrated software.